# Import patients in Bundle to FHIR server

Tags: curl, bundle, hl7-fhir

I'm trying to import a Bundle of Patient resources to a FHIR server using cURL.  Here's my command and the response:

```
curl --header "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -k -i -u 'fhiruser:change-password' --data @10patients.json 'https://localhost:9443/fhir-server/api/v4/Bundle'
HTTP/2 201 
location: https://localhost:9443/fhir-server/api/v4/Bundle/17621baad7c-6fdc1153-38d8-4987-9be3-0d4f0983dbac/_history/1
etag: W/"1"
last-modified: Wed, 02 Dec 2020 04:34:10 GMT
date: Wed, 02 Dec 2020 04:34:10 GMT
content-length: 0
content-language: en-US
```

It appears to have worked.  If I GET the bundle itself I can do that; but if I try to access any of the individual Patient resources by id or to get all the Patient resources, I get nothing.  It seems they're accessible only as a part of the Bundle.  For instance:

```
curl -i -s -k -u 'fhiruser:change-password' -X GET 'https://localhost:9443/fhir-server/api/v4/Patient'
```

or

```
curl -i -s -k -u 'fhiruser:change-password' -X GET 'https://localhost:9443/fhir-server/api/v4/Patient/17621b90c2f-492f5677-f480-4ef8-8b6a-4a2ebfbad715'
```

return nothing.

Here's the beginning of the data file containing the patient resources:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "id": "b248b1b2-1686-4b94-9936-37d7a5f94b51",
  "meta": {
    "lastUpdated": "2012-05-29T23:45:32Z"
  },
  "type": "batch",
  "entry": [
    {
      "fullUrl": "http://hl7.org/fhir/Patient/1",
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Patient",
        "id": "1",
        "meta": {
          "lastUpdated": "2012-05-29T23:45:32Z"
        },
        "text": {
          "status": "generated",
          "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Everywoman, Eve. SSN:\n            444222222</div>"
        },
        "identifier": [
          {
            "type": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
                  "code": "SS"
                }
              ]
            },
            "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-ssn",
            "value": "444222222"
          }
        ],
        "active": true,
        "name": [
          {
            "use": "official",
            "family": "Everywoman",
            "given": [
              "Eve"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "telecom": [
          {
            "system": "phone",
            "value": "555-555-2003",
            "use": "work"
          }
        ],
        "gender": "female",
        "birthDate": "1973-05-31",
        "address": [
          {
            "use": "home",
            "line": [
              "2222 Home Street"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "managingOrganization": {
          "reference": "Organization/hl7"
        }
      },
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "Patient"
      }
    },
    {
      "fullUrl": "http://hl7.org/fhir/Patient/2",
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Patient",
        "id": "2",
        "meta": {
          "lastUpdated": "2012-05-29T23:45:32Z"
        },
        "text": {
          "status": "generated",
          "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Everyman, Adam. SSN:\n            444333333</div>"
        },
        "identifier": [
          {
            "type": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
                  "code": "SS"
                }
              ]
            },
            "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-ssn",
            "value": "444333333"
          }
        ],
        "active": true,
        "name": [
          {
            "use": "official",
...
```

As you can see I used "type": "batch" in the data file.  I also tried "type": "transaction" but that had the same results.
Obviously I can import the patients on at a time using a shell script but I'd prefer to import the whole bundle at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the standard, when you post the bundle to [base]/Bundle, you are asking the server to store the batch / transaction like any other Bundle. when you post it to [base] then it will be processed

See http://hl7.org/fhir/bundle.html#rest

Comment: Is the scenario about posting bundles to [base] still covered in the FHIR specs? The referenced section above does say that items posted to the /Bundle endpoint are treated as static resources, but I'm not finding any reference to posting to [base] for processing.

Comment: Nevermind. Found the reference I was looking for: https://www.hl7.org/fhir/http.html#transaction.